# Check the word after a '@' character in PHP

Tags: php, character

I'm making a news and comment system at the moment, but  I'm stuck at one part for a while now. I want users to be able to refer to other players on the twitter style like **@username**. The script will look something like this: (not real PHP, just imagination scripting ;3)

```
$string = "I loved the article, @SantaClaus, thanks for writing!";
if($string contains @){ 
    $word = word after @;
    $check = is word in database? ...
}
```

And that for all the @username's in the string, perhaps done with a while(). I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a RegEx in this situation, you may want to check [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Rumor has it people call it *pseudocode*

Comment: @Alexander - I kinda like it though. _Imagination scripting._ "What do you do for work, Alex?" "_Imagination scripting._" O_o'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is where **regular expressions** come in.

```
<?php
    $string = "I loved the article, @SantaClaus! And I agree, @Jesus!";
    if (preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)@(\w+)/', $string, $matches))
    {
        $users = $matches[1];
        // $users should now contain array: ['SantaClaus', 'Jesus']
        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            // check $user in database
        }
    }
?>
```

1. The `/` at beginning and end are *delimiters* (don't worry about these for now).
2. `\w` stands for a *word character*, which includes `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`.
3. The `(?<!\w)@` is a bit advanced, but it's called a *negative lookbehind assertion*, and means, "An `@` that does *not* follow a word character." This is so you don't include things like email addresses.
4. The `\w+` means, "One or more word characters." The `+` is known as a *quantifier*.
5. The parentheses around `\w+` *capture* the portion parenthesized, and appear in `$matches`.

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) seems to be a popular choice of tutorial, but there are plenty of others online.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a job for preg_replace_callback():

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/', function ($matches) {
  if ($user = get_user_by_username(substr($matches[0], 1)))
    return '<a href="user.php?user_id='.$user['user_id'].'">'.$user['name'].'</a>';
  else
    return $matches[0];
}, $string);
```

Comment: +1 This certainly works, but will probably confuse newer developers. Maintainability is important. This can be done without obscure functions and without regular expressions. But 6 of one, half dozen the other.

Comment: I disagree. Regular expressions and functions (even anonymous) are nothing obscure. In fact I find this clearer (because the *intention* is immediately obvious to someone who knows the language) than your solution.

Comment: I wish it was true that most code was maintained by people who understand the language. You may think it isn't your fault if your successors don't know the language, but all that will matter then is if they can understand the code or not. But I agree, everyone SHOULD know these things.

Answer (score 3):

Consider to use the Twitter API for catching the username from your text: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js

Comment: Maybe a bit heavyhanded for OP, but +1 for considering an existing solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an expression that'll match what you need, but won't capture email addresses:

```
$str = '@foo I loved the article, @SantaClaus, thanks for writing to my@email.com';
preg_match_all('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])(@[a-z0-9_]+)/i', $str, $matches);
//$matches[2][0] => @foo
///$matches[2][1] => @SantaClause
```

As you can see: my@email.com isn't captured, but the @foo and @SantaClaus strings *are*...