# how to get word after @ from string in php

Tags: php, regex

if the string is

```
$abc = "hello @john what are you doing";
```

How to get `john` from string. word after `@` sign. Maybe regex is used but I can't figure out how this can be done. 
For I know how to change specific word using `str_replace()`  but I'm not getting how to get that specific word after `@` sign.

Comment: it is near impossible to get "jhon" from that string.

Comment: @Marged `preg_match_all` and then `preg_replace` ? :P

Comment: can you tell me how to get @john  from string ?

Comment: Asked many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416147/php-get-word-directly-after-certain-word-in-string              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043076/check-the-word-after-a-character-in-php

Comment: Even if you get a regex here, what is going to help you maintain code you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$abc = "hello @john what are you doing";
$found = preg_match('/@([^-\s]*)/', $abc, $matches);

$name = null;
if ($found) {
  $name = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: what if there is a-zA-z0-9 after @ sign will it work ?

Comment: If you run the regex on a site like regex101 it will explain it to you. This expression is searching for an `@` then any character that is not a `-` or whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression with a capture group.

```
preg_match('/@(\w+)/', $abc, $match);
$name = $match[1];
```

Comment: If you use preg_match_all it'll return all ocurrences [See the code](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/col)

Comment: @ThiagoAugustusOliveira If it's like SO comments, he might only want the first one.

Comment: He already chosen the answer, but I just want to give a small contribution on the answer that I chosen as the better answer. Anyway thanks.